# can apt do everthing dpkg can?

Tags: server, apt, dpkg, administration

As I understand things apt uses dpkg are there any operations that you can do with dpkg that can't be done with apt? as a new User to Ubuntu server do I need to learn anything about dpkg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, dpkg can do much more than apt-*.

Ubuntu and other Debian derivatives rely on the *.deb package infrastructure.

**dpkg**

*dpkg* is the application that handles the packaging tasks of applications bundled in the *.deb files.  You can do anything with it that apt can do, at a lower level.  You can search, obtain information, view the files, extract, install, remove, configure, etc. with it.

**dselect**

*dselect* is a curses (terminal gui) frontend for dpkg.

**apt**

*Apt* is the Advanced Packaging Tool.  With it you can automate a number of steps you would need to do by hand to obtain the results with dpkg.  Apt works with the *.deb packages found in repositories to the point that you may not even know the files are there.

**aptitude**

*aptitude* is a curses (terminal gui) frontend for apt-*.

**synaptic**

*synaptic* is a gtk+ (desktop gui) frontend apt-*.

**Notable usage for *dpkg*:**

`dpkg -c` - Shows the contents of a deb package.

`dpkg -i` - Installs a deb package.

`dpkg -s` - Shows information about the installed package.

`dpkg --reconfigure` - Runs the configuration dialogs that you saw when installing the package.

**Notable usage for *apt-get*:**

`apt-get install` - Installs a package from your configured repositories.

`apt-get remove` - Uninstalls a package.

`apt-get update` - Updates your cache of packages within your repositories.

`apt-get upgrade` - Upgrades your installed packages if applicable.

`apt-get dist-upgrade` - Used to migrate to the latest distribution release.

`apt-get autoremove` - Uninstalls packages that were not explicitly installed and are not needed.

**Notable usage for *apt-cache*:**

`apt-cache search` - Searches to see if a specified package is available in your repositories.

`apt-cache stats` - Gives statistics on repositories in cache.

Answer (score 3):

`apt` and `dpkg` perform different but orthogonal tasks.  `dpkg` keeps track of what packages are currently installed, and can install or remove them.  `apt` keeps track of what packages are available and can do things like download a package ( and its dependencies ) and hand them to `dpkg` to install, or check if there are newer versions of the packages you have installed, download them, and hand them to `dpkg` to install.

In other words, `dpkg` handles the low level package management, and `apt` builds on top of it by adding the concept of an archive that contains packages that you may want to download and install.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, `apt` can't be used to install a package from a .deb file; you’d have to use `dpkg -i` for that.

Otherwise, don’t worry about it.  If you know your way around `apt`, by all means use that.
If you run into limitations of `apt`, at least you’ll already know to look into `dpkg`.  :-)