# Why does Ubuntu use apt instead of dpkg?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I would like official documentation explaining why Ubuntu uses `apt` instead of `dpkg`.

Here's what I've found about each:

`dpkg`

> This package provides the low-level infrastructure for handling the
> installation and removal of Debian software packages.

`apt`

> This package provides commandline tools for searching and  managing as
> well as querying information about packages  as a low-level access to
> all features of the libapt-pkg library.

Comment: Your official answer is "Which is better to use for the end user?  `apt` or `dpkg`?  And the answer becomes "`dpkg` is not able to download from source repositories, etc. it's a 'dumb tool' to install Debian packages in .deb format.  `apt` is what actually *downloads* from the repositories and checks for repository updates, etc. and then knows what to download when you run `apt install` for a given package.  `dpkg` is the 'dumb tool', whereas `apt` is the smart tool and can help decipher what dependencies also need installed, etc. and then handle yelling if there's an uninstallable package.

Comment: @ThomasWard is this a point of view or do you have documentation to support this?

Comment: See for yourself. You can run `man apt` and `man dpkg` -- Ubuntu has **both** `apt` and `dpkg`. All Debian based distributions have both `apt` and `dpkg`.  `apt` is just a user friendly, more intelligent, dependency resolving front end for the lower level `dpkg`. If you want more information, read the duplicate I have posted. Everything you've asked here is covered in the duplicate.

Comment: The phrasing of the question ("*A instead of B*") is confusing. What leads you to believe that A and B are exclusive?

Comment: @AlexPixel apart from the data you already pulled, manpages and other posts online and here to support it.  Plus the fact I'm an Ubuntu Developer and a Debian package maintainer and have been using Ububtu Linux as my primary driver OS since 2009... :P

Comment: Your question is not being answered as you asked it because the premise of the question is wrong.  Ubuntu doesn't use apt instead of dpkg, it uses both, and apt relies on dpkg to do the low level package installation steps after apt resolves dependencies and downloads the packages.

Comment: See also:
* https://askubuntu.com/questions/705885/difference-between-dpkg-i-and-apt-get-install
* https://askubuntu.com/questions/91205/can-apt-do-everthing-dpkg-can

Comment: I'm not blocking it, everyone else is.  It is a duplicate, but you aren't reading (or aren't understanding) the other answers to understand why it is a duplicate.  And when you re-ask the exact same question without even changing the words, it's certainly a duplicate -- that's why that one got deleted.