# How can I search for packages installed ONLY with APT?

Tags: apt, dpkg, aptitude

Paying attention to:

- Only `apt`
- Not `dpkg`
- Not `apt-get`
- Not `aptitude`

Comment: You may want to check your bash history to look for instances where things were installed with `apt` and not `apt-get`, which is the exact same thing. Otherwise, if both are valid search options, there's the `history.log` file(s) in `/var/log/apt`.

Comment: @matigo I don't think so, there's an answer for APT

Comment: That is a very unusual thing to want to find. Mind explaining _why_ you want to do that? I strongly suspect you have [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here

Comment: @unusual is my specialty

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the premise for the question does not exist - everything listed in the question uses `dpkg` to install packages.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

### 1_ there's such thing

It supports glob patterns for matching package names as well as options to list:

1. installed (--installed)
2. upgradeable (--upgradeable)
3. all available (--all-versions) versions.

search for all packages:

```bsh
apt list
```

search for a package **installed** or **not**

```bsh
apt list <package-name>
apt list gnome-calculator #example
```

**returns**

```javascript
gnome-calculator/jammy,now 1:41.1-2ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

### 2_ even deeper [show installed and upgradable]

```bsh
apt list -a google-chrome-stable
```

**returns**

```javascript
google-chrome-stable/stable 101.0.4951.54-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 101.0.4951.41-1]
google-chrome-stable/now 101.0.4951.41-1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 101.0.4951.54-1]
```

1. `apt list` is similar to dpkg-query `dpkg -s` but with **dpkg** is longer and **needs** to uses other tooling to filter result like grep.

```
dpkg -s google-chrome-stable | grep "Status"` //with dpkg
Status: install ok installed //returns
```

Comment: You are incorrect in your assumptions. Finding installed packages with `apt list` will also list packages installed using `dpkg`, `apt-get` and `aptitude`, because they all install packages using `dpkg` as the back-end.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing, because apt doesn't install packages, it finds and downloads packages to install and their dependencies  and then gives them to dpkg to install.  So all packages installed with apt are actually installed with dpkg.

See also:

- [Difference between `dpkg -i` and `apt-get install`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705885/difference-between-dpkg-i-and-apt-get-install)
- [can apt do everthing dpkg can?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91205/can-apt-do-everthing-dpkg-can)

Comment: Note that apt keeps a log of what it installed, but dpkg does not; but you could get a list of installed packages.  So at least until the apt log expires, you could cross check those and get a list of things installed with dpkg that didn't use apt.  But the log is ephemeral, and you'd have to do it by process of elimination.  The reverse is not possible unless there's a dpkg log I didn't notice.